# Aligning html Files

Tags: java, xslt

I am converting xml to html using xslt1.0.My result html is in scattered form like,

```
span style="
             font-family:Cambria;
         font-weight:bold;
             color:#848057;
         font-size:14pt;
             font-family:Cambria;
         font-weight:bold;
             color:#848057;
         font-size:14pt;
                         white-space:pre-wrap;

                     ">Overview</span>
```

I want it to be aligned as a single line. Which tools makes this for me or any other ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without reduce input sample, exact desired output, complete stylesheet or relationship explanation, this is not a real question.

Comment: Can you post the relevant XSLT that is producing the `@style`?  It is likely that you have carriage returns/line feeds in the area that is producing the `@style` attribute value and have mixed literal text with XSLT instructions and the whitespace is seen as significant, and carried into the output.  Wrapping the literal text with `<xsl:text>` will likely solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Where does the spacing come from in the first place?

It looks like you have white-space not treated properly.  It can either come from the incoming XML or as accidental text-nodes in your XSLT.   The cure depends on the origin.

You might find these two articles on dealing with white-space interesting:  http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/11/07/whitespace.html and http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/12/05/whitespace.html